# Queries Always Require Table Name to be Preceded by Owner

Tags: sql-server-2008

We recently changed the ownership of all tables from dbo to another existing login(user). Since the change, I must now precede the table name with the name of the new owner whenever I create a query in SQL Server Management Studio (2008), even though the default database is set correctly. Other folks in my group are not required to do this even if we use the same login for SQL Server Management Studio. I'm thinking this must be a personal setting for the Management Studio on my computer but I can't find a setting that would apply to this problem.

Does anyone know of a default setting the would specify the table owner so I don't have to when I create a query?

Thanks for any help you can give,

TJ

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a [default schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173463.aspx) for a database user not linked to a windows login/group.

Otherwise, it's best practice to qualify objects with schema anyway. This helps execution plan re-use because object references are unambiguous.

Rather then explain here, some references: [one](http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/tip-schema-qualify-objects-in-sps/), [two](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/tibor_karaszi/archive/2007/12/08/owner-schema-qualifying-object-names.aspx), [three](http://www.midnightdba.com/Jen/2010/12/tip-schema-qualify-objects-in-sps/)